# Line integral of scalar field

Tags: line-integrals

I couldn't develop the parametric curve nor I didn't understand very well

This is the question:

[image: 1]

There is the answer:

[image: 2]

I tried  $\int_{0}^{1}(3y-\sqrt{z})ds = \int_{0}^{1}(2y)ds$ because $z=y^2$ but didn't work

I used first this parametric:

A(1,0,0) to B (1,2,4)
x(t) = 1
y(t) = 2t
z(t) = 4t

I tried more things but didn't find the correct answer. 
Someone please could help me understand how to find the correct parametric curve to apply in integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He has **given** you the parametrization, namely $x=1$ and $z=y^2$. This parametrization is in terms of $y$. This means you substitute whatever is inside the integral with these given parameters and compute $ds$, which is the length of the tangent vector: $$\| {\mathbf r}'(y) \| = \| (1,y,y^2) \| = \sqrt{1+(2y)^2} = \sqrt{1+4y^2}.$$ Notice that $0 \leq y \leq 2$. Write the integral in terms of $y$ and you will find the desired answer.

Comment: many thanks! I could find this $\int_{0}^{2}(2y)\sqrt{1+4y^2}dy = 11,51$